# Script to redirect URL if it contains feedburner

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am using Wordpress, I would like to accomplish the redirection but I don't know how.

For example this URL: myblog.com/sample-post/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed&m=1

I would like my site if it detects the word "?utm_source=feedburner" go ahead and replace any string after the feedburner to nothing, so that the redirection occurs to just myblog.com/sample-post

Comment: Give us some context here. **Why** would you want to do this? And why should this be a wordpress task rather than something the webserver should take care of?